# How to remove the big image preview space in XML Preview on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

After updating **Android Studio** to *2022.1.1 Patch 2*, I noticed an issue where the images preview space got bigger :

[image]

I tried to minimize it using the mouse, but it's not working, is there any solution for this, because it's taking up a lot of my screen?

Comment: Did you find a solution because on my laptop 15 inch screen this is also very annoying...